# header menu using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

how to add sub menu under Sub header and call it using CSS, i need it to display contents automatically when the mouse place on it.

```
 <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
          <li><a runat="server" href="~/About">About</a></li>
          <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a runat="sever"  href="#">Sub></a></li>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need some CSS Rules for this:

1. A class that hides your `nav` class inside of the `collapse` class
2. A class that displays your `nav` class inside of `collapse` class when `collapse` is hovered.

When you hover over the `Menu` in the snippet, you will see your items being displayed. Additionally, when you hover over `File` or `Edit` you will see the `li` tags contained in each.

```css
.collapse {
  background-color: #AAA;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
}

.nav {
  padding:10px;
  margin:0;
}

.collapse .nav {
  display : none;
}

.collapse:hover .nav {
  display : block;
  border-top: 1px solid #555;
}

.nav li {
  display : none;
}

.nav:hover li {
  display : block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
  Menu
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    File
    <li><a href="~/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="~/About">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="~/Contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    Edit
    <li><a href="#">Cut</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Copy</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Paste</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Select All</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: how to do the same thing  for Sub header ?

Comment: I need the above code for Sub menu only not for the main menu..how to do that ?

Comment: I added code for the submenu. I also added some colors and borders that hopefully help explain.